# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, cllocationmanager, appledoc

Im using `-startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` in my application.

Application when in background

`- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation`

method called. I want to call API in didUpdateToLocation(when application in background). When location significant change above method called. In that method i called my API. All this happen in background and all are works well. I want to know is it ok? I didn't have good idea about apple documentation. I think this method apple wont reject. Any one please give me some idea.

Thanks

Comment: I think in my view, the approach you have followed is the standard approach all applications follow when in the background! will definitely not be rejected when published on the app store!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a deprecated api. This  method deprecated in iOS 6, and was replaced by :

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

If you want to support earlier versions you should implement them both.

Good luck

p.s.
Apple will never reject a method from their own public api.